# Multiple actions in a certain time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a list of **only** (Client_ID) and (**Client first** Purchase_date).

**However**, there’s a **Client Criteria**: return only the clients who have made their **second  purchase within max 50 days** of their first purchase_date.

```
Client_id | Purchase_date | purchase_type_id | Billing_ID
---------------------------------------------------------
01        | 05-Jan-19     | 1                |  010
01        | 18-Jan-19     | 2                |  018
02        | 05-Feb-19     | 1                |  021
03        | 18-Apr-19     | 3                |  029
03        | 01-Aug-19     | 3                |  030
04        | 05-Aug-19     | 2                |  049
05        | 05-Aug-19     | 2                |  059
06        | 05-Aug-19     | 1                |  060
```

***Purchase Type ID:** (1) For (New Client), (2) for (Repeat Client), (3) for (Same Item like the previous purchase).

According to this, the query must only contain Client_id = 01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select client_id, min(purchase_date)
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.client_id = t.client_id and
                    t2.purchase_date <= t.purchase_date + interval '50 day' and
                    t2.purchase_date > t.purchase_date

             )
group by client_id;
```

I don't think you need the `purchase_type_id` for this, assuming the dates are correct.

EDIT:

Actually, this might be a better approach because it avoids the outer aggregation:

```
select client_id, min(purchase_date)
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.client_id = t.client_id and
                    t2.purchase_date <= t1purchase_date + interval '50 day' and
                    t2.purchase_date >= t.purchase_date and
                    t2.purchase_type_id <> 1

             )
where t.purchase_type_id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon for your time. I'm so much Grateful.but  if you please,could you interpret the Where clause in the sub-query to me?

Comment: @Nash . . . It is specifying that there is another purchase in the first fifty days, after the first purchase.  I added a revised version, which allows the second purchase to be on the same date -- and should be faster.

Comment: You really helped me out with your two great solutions. Again and again, thank you, Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

[Click: step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d93d1587badfac2c6e3cd186b0c79ba1)

You can use the [`lead()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
    "Client_id",
    MIN("Purchase_date")
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        lead("Purchase_date") OVER (PARTITION BY "Client_id" ORDER BY "Purchase_date") 
            - "Purchase_date" AS diff
    FROM
        mytable
) s
WHERE diff <= 50
GROUP BY "Client_id"
```

1. `lead("Purchase_date")` gives you the next purchase date within the group specified in the `PARTITION BY` clause (in your case the `Client_id`)
2. You can take this to calculate the difference to the current purchase date which gives you the number of days
3. Filter all value with difference `<= 50` days
4. If there are multiple purchases within this range, you can give out the minimum date by grouping

Comment: Thank you very much S-Man for your time, effort and help. I'm so much Grateful, dear.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for accepting: Please do not forget to upvote both helpful answers as well (Both given answers are correct!) This honor the work and time of all repliers. Thanks!